# Time series analysis video resources

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, forecasting

I am kinda new in Data Science. My background is in Mathematics. I took some graduate-level statistics courses like the generalized linear model. I am interested to forecast future student enrollment of my university. I was wondering if you could give me some video resources links on Time series analysis. I never took any time series course. I appreciate your help!

Comment: I found this video really good    https://youtu.be/v5ijNXvlC5A

Comment: @psychonomics I guess, she only covered the python implementation of the time series model. Did she discuss the mathematical explanation of time series models?